# Android Gallery not instantly refreshed with new recorded videos

Tags: android, video, gallery

With the following code, the Android Gallery is not refreshed instantly. If i try to see the new files, I need to restart the device or wait.

```
    private void addVideoGallery() {

    File f = new File(outputfilename);
    Intent mediaScannerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri fileContentUri = Uri.fromFile(f); 
    mediaScannerIntent.setData(fileContentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScannerIntent);         


}
```

With this other code, all works fine but in the logcat I see an error that my Activity has leaked MediaScanner Connection:

```
    private void addVideoGallery() {

    File f = new File(outputfilename);
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { f.getPath() }, new String[] {   "video/mp4" }, null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, outputfilename);
      ContentResolver resolver = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();
      resolver.insert(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```