# How can i refresh the Gallery after recording a video?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I am creating an app that does NOT revolve around video/image capturing. However i want to build a simple customizable camera instead of delegating to other app. I have the image capture working as well as the video but when i try to view the gallery after recording or taking a picture i only see that the gallery has been re-indexed to reflect the photos ONLY. I have tried these methods and the videos captured are not inserted into the gallery until after i restart my phone.

```
recordButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isRecording) {
                        // stop recording and release camera
                        mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                        // Tell MediaScanner about new file so that it's immediately available to  user.
                        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                new String[] { getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString()}, null,
                                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                        Log.i("/nExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                    }
                                });
                        releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                        mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder
                        recordButton.setText("RECORD");
                        // inform the user that recording has stopped
                        //setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
                        isRecording = false;
                    } else {
                        // initialize video camera
                        if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                            // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                            // now you can start recording
                            mMediaRecorder.start();

                            // inform the user that recording has started
                            recordButton.setText("STOP");
                            //setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                            isRecording = true;
                        } else {
                            // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                            releaseMediaRecorder();
                            // inform user
                        }
                    }
                }

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mMediaRecorder = null;
        mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    Log.w(TAG, "Environment.getExternalStorageState() = " + Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "------------------------------>");
    Log.w(TAG, "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() = " + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "------------------------------>");

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory--------------------------------------------->");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    Log.w(TAG, "getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString() = " + mediaFile.toString() + " ------------------------------->");
    return mediaFile;
}
// Prepare Video Recorder Steps
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    //mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    Log.w(TAG, "--------------------------------------------------------------Step 4: Set output file:  " + getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are scanning too soon. `stop()` is not instantaneous.

Comment: Actually found A solution via [link]<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555575/android-gallery-not-instantly-refreshed-with-new-recorded-videos> i implemented 
 `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                                         
  values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, outputfilename); 
  ContentResolver resolver = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(); 
  resolver.insert(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);`